# Using LINQ in VB.NET with namespaces

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, linq

I have this XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>NuSpecID</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <title>NuSpec Sample</title>
    <authors>Jim Bob</authors>
    <owners>Billy Joel</owners>
    <licenseUrl>http://url.goes.here</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>http://url.goes.there</projectUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>ture</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>this is a sample nuget.</description>
    <summary>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

and this code:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim root As XElement = XElement.Load("c:\tmp\nuspec.xml")
        Dim tests As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = _
            From el In root.<metadata> _
            Select el
        For Each el As XElement In tests
            Console.WriteLine(el.<id>.Value)
        Next
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
End Module
```

If I take out the `xmlns="HTTP..."` my code outputs "NuSpecID", but I cannot find a solution that allows me to parse/query this XML with the namespace still attached.

I also have some files that do not have a namespace or have a different one, how do I determine whether or not to use one and which one to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to [import the namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384589.aspx) to use in XML literals.

At the top of the module, put:

```vb
Imports <xmlns:ns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
```

Then in your function:

```vb
Dim tests = root.<ns:metadata>

For Each el In tests
    Console.WriteLine(el.<ns:id>.Value)
Next
```

Obviously you can use anything instead of `ns`.

Comment: Or you could set the default namespace with `Imports <xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">` so you don't have to specify the namespace every time.

Comment: I have adjusted my question, i have multiple options for namespaces based on what file i select. how do i write one function that can have different namespaces?

Comment: @theB3RV You are supposed to know what namespaces your XMLs use, that is the whole point of namespaces. If you do know what namespace each file contains, `Import` them all at the top of your module with different prefixes and use accordingly. If you don't know the namespaces, which means you don't care about them and what to ignore them, then write your XML queries in the form of `From el In Root.Elements Where el.Name.LocalName = "metadata" Select el`.