# VB 2010 XML files with namespaces are causing trouble

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq, namespaces

I'm trying to parse out an XML file using LINQ (XDocument) and there's something about having a namespace in the document that screws everything up.

I found [this SO question about the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150719/using-linq-in-vb-net-with-namespaces) affecting element names, and I got past that (using the `Name.LocalName` property). But it's causing the same problem with other functions, such as getting an element with a specific name. For example:

The XML code in brief:

```
<FeatureDefinitions xmlns="http://website.com/schema/features">
    <FeatureDefinition  Name="FeatureOne" >
      <Attributes>
        <ListAttribute Name="TYPE" Description="MATERIAL USED.">
          <ListItems>
            <Item>Material 1</Item>
            <Item>Material 2</Item>
            <Item>OTHER </Item>
          </ListItems>
        </ListAttribute>
        <ListAttribute Name="POSITION">
          <ListItems>
            <Item>BEGIN</Item>
            <Item>EDGE</Item>
            <Item>END</Item>
            <Item>TOE</Item>
            <Item>TOP</Item>
          </ListItems>
        </ListAttribute>
        <StringAttribute Name="NOTES" />
      </Attributes>
    </FeatureDefinition>
</FeatureDefinitions>
```

Then in the code:

```
Dim nodeFeatureDef as XElement = nodeFeatureDefinitions.Element("Attributes")
```

So, what's happening now is that when the name space is included in the first line of the XML, I can't get the `element("Attributes")` and its associated nodes. But if I delete the namespace attribute in the first line, it works fine.

There are lots of forums in which it is suggested that the VB source code import the namespace, but I can't be sure every file that this processes will have the same namespace. It worked by using the `Name.LocalName` property to the Name property, but I don't know how to do the same thing to the Elements property.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the namespace is unknown, you could get it from the root element:

```
Dim xml As XDocument = ...
Dim ns = xml.Root.Name.Namespace
```

You can then use the [`XNamespace.GetName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.getname(v=vs.110).aspx) method to create a qualified name, e.g.

```
Dim attrs = xml.Descendants(ns.GetName("ListAttribute"))
```

This should also work OK if there is no namespace on the root element.

Comment: I think we have a winner! Slight modification to the code structure for my application, and it seems to be doing perfectly so far.Thanks!